# How to set body move in specific trajectory in Box2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d

How to make some body move in specific trajectory?

I need some body to move up and down continuously ignoring gravity. Is there any way to do this with some body, or should i make it manually creating a new body in specific position in every iteration?

Answer (score 1):

You must write the code for where it should be and just set its position before each simulation step. Also set its velocity if you want other objects that might bounce off it to behave correctly. Also give it infinite mass so it is a fixed object and won't be moved by things hitting it.

Set infinite mass like this when you create the body:

```
bodyDef.type = b2_staticBody;
```

Comment: Help please how to set infinite mass to this body. *b2MassData massData;
    _body->GetMassData(&massData);
    massData.mass = 0;
    
    _body->SetMassData(&massData);* This doesn't help

Comment: Sorry for my confusing way of explaining it - it's the body type you must set in code to static body - this implies infinite mass.

Comment: As i understand i can not change linear velocity or set any impulse to the static body, that is why i try to make it dynamic and change the mass

Comment: Kinematic body type would be better because they are designed to move around.